# Group data frame by date and create a new average score dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a df:

```
                score            created_at 
0                0.00   2021-04-04 08:28:08       
1                0.25   2021-04-04 08:18:03      
2               -0.20   2021-04-04 08:09:54   
3                0.15   2021-04-03 06:08:55      
4                0.19   2021-04-03 06:08:55
```

I would like to group the scores by date creating an average score for each day. For example, group all the scores for date 2021-04-04 (which are 0.00,0.25 and-0.2) and create and average which in this case would be 0.01666.

So my desired new data frame output would look like:

```
      date   average_score
2021-04-03         0.01666
2021-04-04         0.17000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['created_at']=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
#Ensure that 'created_at' is of dtype datetime
```

Finally:

```
out=df.groupby(df['created_at'].dt.date)['score'].mean().reset_index()
```

OR

```
out=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at',freq='1D'))['score'].mean().reset_index()
```

OR

```
out=df.groupby(df.pop('created_at').dt.floor('D'))['score'].mean().reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    created_at  score
0   2021-04-03  0.170000
1   2021-04-04  0.016667
```

If needed use:

```
out=out.rename(columns={'created_at':'date','score':'average_score'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `created_at` is of type `datetime`, you can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and get your result in one line:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='D')).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'created_at': 'date', 'score': 'average_score'})
```

```sh
        date  average_score
0 2021-04-03       0.170000
1 2021-04-04       0.016667
```